# ODBC error while importing tables from quickbooks online to power bi

Tags: powerbi, odbc, powerbi-desktop, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am facing an issue while importing data from quickbooks online(beta) connector to power bi.

After selecting a table for preview getting below error.

```
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DSI] (20030) Memory management error.
Details:
DataSourceKind=QuickBooksOnline
DataSourcePath=QuickBooksOnline
OdbcErrors=[Table]
```

Below is my data load config

[image]

Tried changing data cache size and parallel loading count.
Also tried verifying the table in quickbooks online, it has closely 100k records.
Not sure what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error was showing up in Power Query Editor but the table data actually loaded and I could create reports against it.  My table was actually **SalesReceipt_Sales_Item_Line** so I needed to find where the lengthy text was coming from.  There are several ways to do this but here is the quick and dirty method I used that finally got rid of the error.

I started with the **Line_Description** field and created a calculated column in the target table with DAX to find the length:

```
Line_Description_Lenth = LEN([Line_Description])
```

I also created another calculated column with DAX to form a link directly to the **Sales Receipt** to make things easy to edit:

```
Link_to_Sales_Receipt = CONCATENATE(
    "https://app.qbo.intuit.com/app/salesreceipt?txnId=", [Id]
)
```

*(note, you might need to swap out the link for your environment or specific transaction type, mine was '**salesreceipt**')*

Once the link column is created, click it, and go to the **Column tools** tab at the top in your ribbon.  Change the **Data category** to **Web URL**.

I then added a matrix visual to the canvas and dragged over the newly created **Line_Description_Length** as the first row, **Link_to_Sales_Receipt** as the second row, and **Count of Id** for the values.

Sort by **Line_Description_Length** in descending order and start opening the transactions to shorten the long text values.

In the end, I had 6 or so that were over 1000 due to long descriptions I had copied and pasted from a website for the product.  The max size in my list is now 844 and it loads as expected.  I went in and edited the descriptions of the items that were causing the issue to avoid running into it again in the future.

Link to original post with screenshots:

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/DataSource-Error-ODBC-ERROR-HY000-Microsoft-DSI-20030/m-p/3661591/highlight/true#M1197054